# validating fields in datatable using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an excel sheet which contains fields like

```
employee ID,Employee Name,Email,Phone
```

and their respective values.

I want to import that excel sheet and then apply data validations to each field.

I have created two folders in my local system, if the validation succeeds then move the excel sheet to first folder and if there is any validation error then move it to second folder.

What i tried is to import the excel sheet in a data table using oledb connection.

The problem is that after that how to do validations. I am implementing the project in asp.net using `c#`, if it was a `MVC` then I could have added `Data Annotations` in model class but i have to implement it in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Use asp.net webforms authentication on your choice may be this link will be helpfull 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527.aspx
or using regular expression like this 
[Click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/66489a/client-side-validation-for-email-in-asp-net/)